# Call Objective C Method from URL webView

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I have a `webView` which has URLs link to KEYWORD. Upon clicking the URL, I would like to call the following method:

```
[self.db fetchDefinitionsWithKeyword:@"KEYWORD" callback:^(NSDictionary *response) {
        NSString *HTML = [self.HTMLRenderer renderHTML:response];
        [self.webView loadHTMLString:HTML baseURL:nil];
```

In Android, we can use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. How should I do that in Objective C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code may be its helpfull for you.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) 
    {
        // you can call any thing on click.
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

if you want do at your click, you can judge the `navigationType` is `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked`. otherwise you can ignore `navigationType`. 
all `webview` request go through this method . good luck.